# c++ initialize std::array of std::arrays in the initializer list using constructor parameters

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a constructor as such:

```cpp
class MyClass {
  protected:
    std::size_t size1;
    std::size_t size2;
    std::array<std::array<std::pair<std::uint64_t, std::uint64_t>>> items;
  public:
    MyClass(): MyClass(1, 1, <???>) {}
    MyClass(std::size_t size1, std::size_t size2): size1(size1), size2(size2), <???> {}
};
```

I'm not sure if the above  part can be done: to initialize the array of arrays of pairs to all 0 based on the sizes provided by size1 and size2. I've Googled around a bit but can't seem to run into code examples of this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot. `std::array` size is fixed and must be known at compile time. You might want to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: If you have sufficient storage available and you know the maximum possible size of the array, you can allocate for the maximum size and use only the portion of the the array required by the user. This is sometimes preferable to using `std::vector`, but usually only when the maximum possible size is fairly small.

Answer (score 3):

As Yksisarvinen mentioned, `std::array` needs to know its size at compile time. If you need to set the size at runtime, then use `std::vector` instead. However, if you *do* know the size at compile time, then make `MyClass` a template and pass the desired sizes as template parameters:

```
template<std::size_t size1 = 1, std::size_t size2 = 1> {
protected:
    std::array<std::array<..., size2>, size1> items{};
public:
    MyClass() = default;
    ...
};
```

Note that the `{}` after the declaration of `items` ensures all the values are set to zero. And then you can instantiate it like so:

```
MyClass<3, 5> myObject;
```